# optimization problem in CV

Tags: optimization, computer-vision

hopefully I'm writing this post in the adequate place if not please move my post

I'm reading this paper about L-shaping fitting for vehicles. and ran into this optimization in the photo attached.

in the paper it is written that due to the combinatorial complexity of the partition problem it is not easy to solve the optimization, but what does partition has to do with it ?

I have a simple solution for each theta given: the given theta creates 2 perpendicular lines(l1,l2) that correspond to P,Q from the paper.
for every point: measure the distance from the point to each line and add the point to the corresponding group of the closest line.

why wouldn't it work? or why is it not computationally possible ?
the algorithm I'm proposing here seems to be O(N*k) - N number of points and k - number of degrees we test

thanks everyone :)

[image]

Comment: You are not suggesting an algorithm, but a point assignment rule. This raises two difficulties: 1) you need to express this assignment in the objective function analytically and 2) your constraint in fact modifies the problem and might lead to a solution that is not optimal in the initial setting.

Comment: By the way, this does not seem to be "your" solution, as it is mentioned in the next paragraphs of the book.

Answer (score 1):

What the author means - and is right in thinking so - is that from an analytical point of view, the optimization is arduous. This is because the objective function depending on the three parameters $\theta,c_1,c_2$, also depends on the assignments of the points to $P$ and $Q$, which can be made in $2^m$ ways.